# Drop Down Check Boxes in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, drop-down-menu, dropdownchecklist

Trying to add multiple records from the checked options of a drop down selection. the value of selection is the same for records created and it should be different. The values is not changing.

```
 If txtShiftgroupID.Text = "" Then
   Dim checkedList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
            'Dim i As Integer = 0
            For Each item As ListItem In ddlshifttype.Items

                If item.Selected Then
                    myShiftGroup.ShiftIDValue = ddlshifttype.SelectedValue
                    item.Selected = ddlshifttype.SelectedValue
                    ShiftGroupMgt.insertShiftGroup(myShiftGroup)

                End If
            Next

        Else
            myShiftGroup.ShiftIDValue = txtShiftgroupID.Text
            ShiftGroupMgt.UpdateShiftGroup(myShiftGroup)
        End If
        lblMsgShiftGroup.Text = "Record save successfully"
        lblMsgShiftGroup.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
        mpeShiftGroup.Show()
        cmdsaveshiftgroup.Enabled = False
        loadShiftGroup()
    End If
```

Comment: Show the code where you filled the list box. Use the edit link to add the information to your question. Take the [tour].

Comment: What is the purpose of this line? `item.Selected = ddlshifttype.SelectedValue`

Answer (score 0):

All the 3 records created were of the same shift type.

There should have been 3 records with different shift types selected from the drop-down checked.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, delete and edit your original question.